# Sequelize Postgres Query on JSONB object generating invalid query

Tags: postgresql, sequelize.js

Definition of Book with user as a json b

```
sequelize.define(
    "Book",
    {
      id: { type: DataTypes.STRING, primaryKey: true },
      name: DataTypes.STRING,
      genre: DataTypes.STRING,
      user: DataTypes.JSONB
    },
    {
      createdAt: false,
      updatedAt: false,
      timestamps: false,
      tableName: "Book",
      paranoid: true,
      schema: "public"
    }
  ); 
  };
```

Query to find all where user.id equals 2

```
Book.findAll({
      where: {
        "user.id": {
          [Op.eq]: "2"
        }
      }
    })
```

Sequelize is generating a query as below

```
SELECT id, name, genre, user, authorId FROM public.Book AS Book WHERE
```

> ("Book.user"#>>'{id}')

```
 = '2';
```

which is resulting in below error

> ERROR:  column "Book.user" does not exist LINE 1: ...e, user, authorId
>   FROM public.Book AS Book WHERE ("Book.user...
>                                                                ^

Need some help in querying based on id of the user object using sequelize

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works , i think there's no need to use [Op.eq].

```
 Book.findAll({
     where: {
        id :  "2"
       }
     })
     .then(result=>{
        console.log(result);
     })
     .catch(error=>{
        console.log(error)
    });
```